# What buffer collects the data sent through TCP sockets on localhost?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

I have a client and server connected through TCP sockets on localhost.

I check with `getsockopt` that the server's `SO_SNDBUF` is small and the client's `SO_RCVBUF` is small (in my case both are 64KB)

I send twenty 500KB buffers from the server to the client, but in the client I've added a sleep for 500ms after each `recv` and I've capped the client receive buffer to 1MB.

What I observe is that the server very quickly rids itself of the 10MB of data which then arrives at the client in the next several seconds. 7-8MB are consistently in the "ether" in my experiments.

My question is what is this "ether"? It's obviously some buffer somewhere but can one tell which buffer it is?

Here is my test program.

```cpp
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

#define PROXY 0

static std::vector<uint8_t> getRandomBuf() {
    std::vector<uint8_t> buf;
    buf.reserve(500 * 1024);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < buf.capacity(); ++i) buf.push_back(rand() % 256);
    return buf;
}

int server() {
    auto sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sd < 0) return puts("socket fail");

    sockaddr_in srv = {};
    srv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srv.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    srv.sin_port = htons(7654);

    int enable = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
        return puts("setsockopt fail");
    }

    if (bind(sd, (sockaddr*)&srv, sizeof(srv)) < 0) {
        return puts("bind fail");
    }

    listen(sd, 3);

    puts("listening...");

    sockaddr_in client;
    socklen_t csz = sizeof(client);
    auto sock = accept(sd, (sockaddr*)&client, &csz);
    if (sock < 0) return puts("accept fail");

    {
        int data;
        socklen_t size = sizeof(data);
        getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &data, &size);
        printf("accepted: %d\n", int(data));
    }

    for (int i=0; i<20; ++i) {
        auto buf = getRandomBuf();
        puts("Server sending blob");
        send(sock, buf.data(), buf.size(), 0);
        puts("  Server completed send of blob");
    }

    while (true) std::this_thread::yield();

    return close(sock);
}

int client() {
    int sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sd < 0) return puts("socket fail");

    sockaddr_in client = {};
    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
#if PROXY
    client.sin_port = htons(9654);
#else
    client.sin_port = htons(7654);
#endif

    if (connect(sd, (sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client)) < 0) {
        return puts("connect fail");
    }

    {
        int data;
        socklen_t size = sizeof(data);
        getsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &data, &size);
        printf("connected: %d\n", int(data));
    }

    std::vector<uint8_t> buf(1024*1024);
    while (true) {
        auto s = recv(sd, buf.data(), buf.size(), 0);
        if (s <= 0) {
            puts("recv fail");
            break;
        }
        printf("Client received %.1f KB\n", double(s)/1024);
#if !PROXY
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
#endif
    }

    return close(sd);
}

int main() {
    std::thread srv(server);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300)); // give time for the server to start
    client();
    srv.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in the test program there is a `#define PROXY 0`.

In another experiment with `PROXY` set to 1, I ditch the sleep and instead connect the client to a throttling proxy (Charles) and throttle the bandwidth to 400KB/s. In this case the server rids itself of the 10MB almost immediately and they arrive in course of ~20 seconds on the client. I assume that the proxy is buffering, though I don't see a configuration in this particular one for the buffer size.

This is all done hunting for another (likely bufferbloat) issue in which the server sends 10MB with 20 packets from Denver to Amsterdam over an Internet connection which does indeed have a 400KB/s bandwidth. In this case the server, much like the throttling proxy example from above, rids itself of the 10MB almost immediately, and they arrive over the next 20 seconds on the client, leading to 20 second delays for any subsequent messages. Had they not left the server, I would've been able to reorder the packets and send higher-priority ones in-between the ones from the 10MB blob, and not have the client suffer a 20 second delay due to network clog.

Comment: here are some relatively educated guesses. (1) i think that sender buffer is actually variable and increases if necessary. [here](https://cromwell-intl.com/open-source/performance-tuning/tcp.html) is an explanation about TCP parameters that control buffer space. I am not sure which one is actually returned, but maybe some of them are actually set to higher values. (2) the next obvious queues are qdisc layer and drivers. I don't think you can do anything with drivers. I am also not sure how exactly localhost one works, but according to ...

Comment: ... [here](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2010/12/14/add-latency-to-localhost/) you can set qdiscs for localhost as well. You could try to set [pfifo](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tc-pfifo) with very small buffer. (3) there is a TCP small queues mechanism that should limit the number of packets not in sender buffer, called [tcp small queues](https://lwn.net/Articles/507065/). According to the link the limit is quite small, but maybe it is configured to larger value.